# Regular expression for Latin Names

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

How can I create a regular expression that identifies first names and family names written as is customary in South America and divide them in the correct order [for example: the full name is "Miguel Juan Sebastián Piñera Echenique". and the short name is "Sebastián Piñera"]

This is a form for US citizens so I can not base the field on a country entered earlier, and it's not appropriate to request Country of Origin). Thanks.

Comment: Regex writing is not mindreading. Can you describe some of the underlying rules? It woudl e.g. not be so hard to extract 3rd and 4th part between spaces...

Comment: You could also show a few of your undoubtedly many own experiments and explain in which way the fail to be satisfying.

Comment: If do not manage to abstract this in any way, then please provide sample input which represents all possible patterns and their combinations. And then hope for somebody doing the rules elicitation for you. On the other hand, with a question that broad, nobody might bother.